# Unable to validate input in C programming

Tags: c

I just started learning **C** and I'm trying to create a simple "Guess the Number" game.

- Player 1 will enter a number that is between 1 and 1000.
- Player 2 will be given 10 chances to guess the number entered by Player 1.
- If Player 2's guess is beyond the range (1 to 1000), the system should display "Invalid. Out of range." instead of "Too high" or "Too low".

**Currently, my program does not validate whether Player 2's guess is within the range (1 to 1000). Instead, it will just display "Too high" even if Player 2's guess is 2000 which is beyond the range (1 to 1000)**

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number, guess, count = 10;

    printf("Enter a number between 1 and 1000:\n");

    scanf("%d",&number);

    while(number < 1 || number > 1000)
    {
        printf("Number is out of range.\n");
        printf("Enter a number between 1 and 1000:\n");
        scanf("%d",&number);
    }

    while(count >= 1 && count <= 10)
    {
        printf("Player 2, you have %d guesses remaining.\n", count);
        printf("Enter your guess:\n");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
        count = count - 1;

        if (guess >= 1 || guess <= 1000)
        {
            if (guess > number)
            {
                printf("Too high.\n");
            }
            else if (guess < number)
            {
                printf("Too low.\n");
            }
            else if (guess == number)
            {
                printf("Player 2 wins.\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid. Out of range.");
        }
    }

    if (count == 0)
    {
        printf("Player 1 wins.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (guess >= 1 || guess <= 1000)` isn't every number  greater or equal to 1 or less than 1000. You want `&&` there most likely.

Comment: You also don't stop when player 2 wins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
 if (guess >= 1 || guess <= 1000)
```

to

```
if (guess >= 1 && guess <= 1000)
```

to avoid values outside 1 and 1000. Otherwise, an input of 2000, will match the condition `guess >= 1` and as per the short circuit property, it'll evaluate the `if` condition as truthy and control will never go to `else` block.

Comment: @canbax technically, we both posted at the same time, `2020-11-02 14:54:00Z`.

Comment: No. When I wrote the answer. I see that your answer was 1 second late. In the first minute, it was written like `35 seconds ago` and `36 seconds ago`. Yours was 1 second later.

Answer (score 0):

`guess >= 1 || guess <= 1000` should be `guess >= 1 && guess <= 1000`